# CVE-2022-22965 - Tomcat Specific

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, wildfly

I am trying to understand the Spring posted description of the problem and resolution alternatives
https://spring.io/blog/2022/03/31/spring-framework-rce-early-announcement

However, I do not understand why this would be Tomcat specific. Wouldnt the same issue exist for war files deployed to Jetty or Wildfly?

Comment: Yes, the existing demonstration is specific to tomcat, but being able to invoke classloaders from the request could exploited in other ways, including in different deployment models or different servlet containers.

Answer (score 0):

This particular exploit demostration is based on the custom custom implementation of one of tomcat specific classloaders having referrence to the servlet environment context. This is why this demo is tomcat specific especially that is exploits the fact that one of the logger valves is the first one in the processing pipeline (this is used to write custom jsp code as a log file in webapps root)

Also it requires Java9+ as it uses access trough class.getModule() which is not present in earlier versions